# Triple integral $\iiint_{D}\cos(x+2y+3z) dV $ over a sphere of radius 1

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

My math problem is to evaluate the integral

$$\iiint_{D}cos(x+2y+3z) dV  $$
  where $D=\left \{ (x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1  \right \}$

I tried approaching it with spherical coordinate by substituting $x=\rho \space \sin\phi \space \cos\theta$, $y=\rho \space \sin\phi \space \sin\theta$, $z=\rho\space  \cos\phi $, but it doesn't help much since the function inside the integral ends up being more complicated. (cosine and sine functions inside cosine)

I also tried using Cartesian coordinate, and changing the integral into
$$8\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} \cos(x+2y+3z) \space \space dzdydx $$
$$=8\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \frac{\sin(x+2y+3\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})-\sin(x+2y)}3 \space \space dydx$$
But I have no idea how to evaluate it, and I don't have any more ideas on this problem.

I see someone else in another post saying we can make use of spherical symmetry and "replace the integrand by $\cos(hz)$, where $h=|(1,2,3)|$. Then, integrate in slices perpendicular to the $z$-axis.", but I have no idea if it would work or why it would work. (and I don't have enough reputation points to comment on that post :( )

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Orthogonal transformation

Comment: I actually haven't learnt orthogonal transformation yet, can you explain a bit more, or tell me how I can apply that to my problem?

Comment: let $ u=\frac{x+2y+3z}{\sqrt{14}},v=a_{1}x+b_{1}y+c_{1}z,w=a_{2}x+b_{2}y+c_{2}z,u^2+v^2+w^2=x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1,dxdydz=dudvdw $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Align the $x$-axis along $(1,2,3)$, the normal direction of the plane $x+2y+3z$, by rotating the angle $\alpha$ around the $z$-axis, followed by the angle $\beta$ around the $y$-axis, with $
\sin\alpha = \frac2{\sqrt5}$ and $
\sin\beta = \frac {3}{\sqrt{14}}$. In the new coordinates, we have

$$u = \frac1{\sqrt{14}}(x+2y+3z), \>\>\>\>\> D=\left \{ u^2+v^2+w^2 < 1  \right \}$$

The integral then simplifies and can be readily integrated in spherical coordinates as follows
\begin{align}
&\int_{D}\cos(x+2y+3z) \ dV  \\
=&\int_{D}\cos(\sqrt{14}u)\ dV 
=\ 2\pi\int_0^1 \int_0^\pi \cos\left(\sqrt{14}r\cos\theta\right)r^2\sin\theta \ dr d\theta \\
= &\ \frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{14}} \int_0^1 \sin(\sqrt{14}r)\ rdr 
= \frac{2\pi}{7}\left(\frac{\sin \sqrt{14}}{\sqrt{14}}- \cos\sqrt{14}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks!